# How can I call another script repeatedly?

Tags: perl, exec

I'm trying to write a Perl script that calls another script, that reads an entire directory.
I don't get any errors, but i don't get the expected result either. I don't get anything on the screen.

I don't need to output anything on screen. The script I'm calling in the `exec()` statement should read each image file into the `DIR` directory, and create a file where it stores some data extracted from that image.
The script in the `exec()` statement should then loop until all images into the directory are read.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use CGI qw/:standard/; 
use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser';

my $dir = '/FilesToRead/';

my $fichier;
my $ligne;
my $mimetype;
my @listeFichiers;

my $cgi = CGI -> new();

opendir (DIR, $dir) or die "Impossible d'ouvrir $dir: $!";
@listeFichiers = grep {/\.mem$/ && -f "$dir/$_"} readdir (DIR);

while (my $ouvRep = readdir(DIR))
{
    foreach $fichier (@listeFichiers)
    {
        exec "v-file ./param.par ./Picture/$fichier -PM_overflow 3000000" or die "Script perl ne s'est pas execute";
    }
}   
closedir DIR;
```

Comment: Thank you all for answers. I'm still not satisfied and have edited my question.

Comment: @unknown You are being silly. In this script, `exec v-file` will happen only once. After that, your script will no longer be running having been replaced with v-file. Incidentally, what does this have to do with CGI?

Answer (score 8):

`exec` replaces the currently running process. See

```
perldoc -f exec
```

You should look at

```
perldoc -f system
```

Answer (score 4):

when you use `exec` it *replaces* the existing perl process with the script you called.  Use `system` instead.

With `exec` the program ends when the `exec`'d script ends.  With `system` the original perl script continues after the `system`'d script ends.

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797127/whats-the-differences-between-system-and-backticks-and-pipes-in-perl) for more details.

Comment: Or back ticks `system request`

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems with your code. The first is there is a logic problem in your use of [`readdir()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html). The first time you use it, with [`grep()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html), it reads in the entire directory and discards anything that [`grep()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) doesn't match. There is nothing else to read in the `while` condition, so it exits the loop without a single iteration.

The second problem is with your use of [`exec()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html). As the [man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) says

> The "exec" function executes a system command and never returns-- use system" instead of "exec" if you want it to return.

The first iteration of your `foreach` loop replaces the current process with the exec'd command. You'll only get output if `v-file` produces it.

I think you mean to use [`system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) here.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```
opendir (DIR, $dir) or die "Impossible d'ouvrir $dir: $!";
@listeFichiers = grep {/\.mem$/ && -f "$dir/$_"} readdir (DIR);

while (my $ouvRep = readdir(DIR))
```

Once you populate `@listeFichiers`, `readdir(DIR)` will then respond with `undef` or `()` depending on scalar or list context.  So, your while loop will loop zero times.

What do you need that while loop for anyway?  You already have the list of files you want.
If you decide you really need it, then [`closedir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/closedir.html) and [`opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) before while

```
opendir (DIR, $dir) or die "Impossible d'ouvrir $dir: $!";
@listeFichiers = grep {/\.mem$/ && -f "$dir/$_"} readdir (DIR);
closedir DIR;

opendir (DIR, $dir) or die "Impossible d'ouvrir $dir: $!";
while (my $ouvRep = readdir(DIR))
```

Or you could call [`rewinddir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rewinddir.html) before the second `while` loop.

```
opendir (DIR, $dir) or die "Impossible d'ouvrir $dir: $!";
@listeFichiers = grep {/\.mem$/ && -f "$dir/$_"} readdir (DIR);

rewinddir (DIR);

while (my $ouvRep = readdir(DIR))
```

Comment: That would be a SAQ: perldoc -f rewinddir. perldoc perlfunc lists all perl functions.

Answer (score 1):

The very first time that exec call gets hit, your process will be replaced. The second (and subsequent) iterations of the loop will never be reached.

If you use system (or backticks if you want output) instead of exec, it should do what you want. What specifically about the answers already give aren't you satisfied with?

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd do this with fork, perhaps with [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parallel::ForkManager). For every item you fork a process which handles it. You can process several things at the same time. You don't have to wait for `system()` to finish. If you are merely trying to trigger this from a CGI script (rather than see results, etc), you might even want to daemonize the dispatcher portion so it goes off on its own to process everything and the CGI process can finish without it.

You might also look at [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IPC-System-Simple) for easy process communication.