# using bash command in perl

Tags: perl, bash, awk

i have short bash code

```
cat example.txt | grep mail | awk -F, '{print $1}' | awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

I want to use it in perl script, and put its output to an array line by line.
I tried this but did not work

```
@array = system('cat /path/example.txt | grep mail | awk -F, {print $1} | awk -F= {print $2}');
```

Thanks for helping...

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797127/whats-the-differences-between-system-and-backticks-and-pipes-in-perl) gives some examples of how to call external programs in Perl.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
@array = `cat /path/example.txt | grep mail | awk -F, {print \$1} | awk -F= {print \$2}')`;
```

Noting that backticks are used and that the dollar signs need to be escaped as the qx operator will interpolate by default (i.e. it will think that $1 are Perl variables rather than arguments to awk).

Comment: It is safer to use open(); It save some escaping.

Answer (score 11):

The return value of `system()` is the return status of the command you executed. If you want the output, use backticks:

```
@array = `cat /path/example.txt | grep mail | awk -F, {print \$1} | awk -F= {print \$2}`;
```

When evaluated in list context (e.g. when the return value is assigned to an array), you'll get the lines of output (or an empty list if there's no output).

Comment: feel free to correct to `array`, a correct answer is worth more than a funny one. I'll remove the silly comments ;)

Comment: I did it but this time awk is not working, it give only output of  'cat /path/example.txt | grep mail' , what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't help making a pure perl version... should work the same, if I remember my very scant awk correctly.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open A, '<', '/path/example.txt' or die $!;
my @array = map { (split(/=/,(split(/,/,$_))[0]))[1] . "\n" } (grep /mail/, <A>);
```