# Is it possible to include oneline command of ubuntu in our own perl script

Tags: perl, command

Is it possible to include one line commands of ubuntu to perl script, which has able to execute inside the script and it should give output as desired. is it possible to do so?

I wish to convert `xlsx` file to `csv` format using `xls2csv` *command*, but I want to execute this command inside my perl script .

Can anyone help me to fix this out ?

Comment: You mean like `system("ls");`?

Comment: i wish to convert xlsx file to csv format using xls2csv command, but i want to execute this command inside my perl script . can  you help me to fix this out !????

Comment: Any basic tutorial will show how to `open(H, "xls2csv $file |")` but you may be better off with a [native Perl library](http://perltricks.com/article/108/2014/8/5/Parse-Excel-with-ease-using-Perl).  Anyway, please update your question to explain what you actually want, what you already tried, and how it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a `shell` command in perl script use `system` like this :

```
system("xls2csv");
```

To store the output of the command, use `backticks` :

```
my $output = `xls2csv`;
```

See the difference between `system` and `backticks` here

[Difference between system, backtics and exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec)

[Differences between system, backticks and pipes in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797127/whats-the-differences-between-system-and-backticks-and-pipes-in-perl)